# Strange nagios-nrpe-server error upgrading from Jessie to Stretch

Tags: debian, apt, monitoring, nagios, dist-upgrade

When upgrading from Jessie to Stretch, at the end of `dist-upgrade`, it ends with an error:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nagios-nrpe-server
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Have tried running apt upgrade, install, and reinstall without correcting this.

What to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To finish installing `nagios-nrpe-server`, I ended up verifying the post-install scripts.

At `nagios-nrpe-server.postinst`:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
# Automatically added by dh_installinit
if [ -x "/etc/init.d/nagios-nrpe-server" ]; then
    update-rc.d nagios-nrpe-server defaults >/dev/null
    invoke-rc.d nagios-nrpe-server start || exit $?
fi
# End automatically added section
```

As I have nagios-nrpe being invoked by (x)inetd and not running as a daemon, it failed startup and thus the `apt dist-upgrade` error.

For the moment commented out the start line, considering whether filing up a bug, and/or changing from `xinetd` to a daemon. I use `xinetd` because I also use it to invoke the backup daemon.

Comment: Please file a bug...

Comment: Bug reported with reportbug